LFS push on self hosted gitlab stops internet on the gitlab server machine
I have a self hosted gitlab(dockerized), SSH over port 2424, on my network. It uses wireless to connect to my network and everything works properly (I can ssh to it, I have internet access and so).
Gitlab works properly as well, I can access it, I can clone/push git both with ssh and https (also both from outside my network and inside my network).
The issue happens when I start pushing multiple bigger files (Unreal Engine uassets in this instance). I use LFS and everything works if I push 1 large file, but when there are multiple, my gitlab host machine stops internet connection fully. Until I do netplan apply, I don't have internet access on the server machine. This does not happen immediatelly, it allows me to push around 100 files, then it stops the internet. After I enable internet on server machine, I can push again, sometimes couple of files, sometimes many files, sometimes it immediatelly stops the internet. I will manage in the end to push the whole repo, but it requires multiple tries and every time I need to phyisically go to my server machine and run netplan apply. By the way, netplan status says it's online, but it does not actually have access to internet or the network itself.
I am not so savy in dev ops with ubuntu and I am not sure how to exactly debug this issue. Any help would be welcome :)
Pushing unreal .uassets to git LFS (files around 1-200mb, around 350 files, push size around 2GB) fully stops internet on gitlab host machine.
